# How to know if text is bigger than textbox?

Tags: c#, wpf

Is there a way to know if my text within a wpf textbox has exceeded the length of it?

**NOTE: I'M TALKING ABOUT PIXEL LENGTH NOT CHARACTER LENGTH OF MAXLENGTH**

So basically, if the textbox is 50 pixels long.
And I have a text in it that is:
"Supercalifragilisticexpialidocious! Even though the sound of it is something quite atrosicous"

Then it won't fit in there right? I'd like to KNOW that it didn't fit in it.
But if the textbox is 900 pixels wide. It just might.

I'm currently checking with something like the following.

```
private double GetWidthOfText()
{
    FormattedText formattedText = new FormattedText(MyTextbox.Text,
        System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-us"),
        FlowDirection.LeftToRight, new Typeface(new FontFamily("Arial"), FontStyles.Normal, FontWeights.Bold, FontStretches.Normal), MyTextbox.FontSize, Brushes.Black);
    return formattedText.Width;
}
```

...

```
if (textBox.Width < GetWidthOfText()) ...
```

But I find it to be incredibly hacky and never really works. I'm trying to find something more reliable. Any ideas?

Comment: Can't you read the maxsize of the text box and then just compare to length of your string?

Comment: I don't want there to be a limit inside the text box (so no maxsize)

Comment: I think you need to check textBox.ActualWidth

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if (textBox.ExtentWidth > textBox.ActualWidth)
{
    // your textbox is overflowed
}
```

Works with .NET 4.5.2

Comment: This is wrong and doesn't answer the question. There is no way the text dimensions are considered to compare it against the textbox dimensions.

Answer (score 7):

You could inherit from the textbox and then create a custom method to return the value you want:

```
public class MyTextBox :TextBox 
{
    public bool ContentsBiggerThanTextBox()
    {
        Typeface typeface = new Typeface(this.FontFamily, this.FontStyle, this.FontWeight, this.FontStretch);
        FormattedText ft = new FormattedText(this.Text, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, System.Windows.FlowDirection.LeftToRight, typeface, this.FontSize, Brushes.Black);
        if (ft.Width > this.ActualWidth)
            return true;

        return false;
    }
}
```

You declare the textbox in the XAML as a MyTextBox instead of TextBox, then you can simply do:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (tb.ContentsBiggerThanTextBox())
        MessageBox.Show("The contents are bigger than the box");
}
```

Comment: worked nicer than mine bc of typeface and actualwidth. thanks!

Answer (score 2):

John Koemer's answer doesn't work if you are not targeting the .NET 4.5 or later framework.

Use this method if you are targeting the .NET 4.0 framework like I am:

```
    private bool IsContentsBiggerThanTextBox(TextBox textBox)
    {
        Size size = TextRenderer.MeasureText(textBox.Text, textBox.Font);
        return ((size.Width > textBox.Width) || (size.Height > textBox.Height));
    }
```

This also works for multi-line textboxes. So if you have more lines than the textbox can display this method also works.

Note that this was actually done in a Windows Forms Application and not a WPF application so I don't guarantee it will work on the WPF side.

Answer (score 0):

Best would be to use a hidden TextBlock and bind it's MinWidth and Text property to the corresponding TextBox. Keep this TextBlock as hidden. When Text surpasses the bounds, the width of hidden textblock will increase as it is having its MinWidth set and not Width. In it's SizeChanged event we check and compare ActualWidth of TextBlock and TextBox. If ActualWidth of TextBlock is more than that of TextBox, this means that text is large.

I have checked this approach with multiple font sizes and works good.

```
<TextBox x:Name="textBox" Width="120" AcceptsReturn="False" TextWrapping="NoWrap" />
<TextBlock x:Name="tblk" TextWrapping="NoWrap" Text="{Binding Text, ElementName=textBox}" MinWidth="{Binding Width, ElementName=textBox}" Visibility="Hidden" SizeChanged="TextBlock_SizeChanged" />
```

code-behind :

```
private void TextBlock_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            //if (e.NewSize.Width > tblk.MinWidth)
            if(tblk.ActualWidth > textBox.ActualWidth)
                tbStatus.Text = "passed";
            else
                tbStatus.Text = "";
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

This should do it.

```
        int tblength = txtMytextbox.MaxLength;
        string myString = "My text";
        if (myString.Length > tblength)
```

I did this in a web form, but since its all on the back end, I assume it should be the same for a winform.